# php mysqli stmt count num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i need get result row count

```
$this-> db = new mysqli("localhost", "***", "***", "***") or die("Error ".mysqli_error($link));
$this-> db -> set_charset("utf8");

$query = "SELECT steps.id, steps.description, steps.sort, services.`name` AS service_name, services.short_name AS service_short_name, terminals.`name` AS terminal_name, terminals.short_name AS terminal_short_name FROM steps INNER JOIN instructions ON steps.page_id = instructions.id INNER JOIN services ON instructions.service_id = services.id INNER JOIN terminals ON instructions.terminal_id = terminals.id WHERE services.short_name = '{$service}' AND terminals.`name` = '{$terminal}' ORDER BY steps.sort";

if ($stmt = $this->db-> prepare($query)) {
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> store_result();
    printf("row count: %d.\n", $stmt -> num_rows);
    $stmt -> close();
}
```

it returns zero - **0** but there are some like 10-15 rows

Comment: Do you have atleast one row within your database/

Comment: @DarylGill i have some like 10-15 rows

Comment: Have you tested your query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: try to test your query in mysql workbench some other editor just to see if your query is okay

Comment: Have your variables been correctly set? Have you tried running the query with actual data found within those rows, to check if it's a SQL or PHP Error?

Comment: add `var_dump($stmt);` in if condition, after `execute()`. Update your question then. we might get idea then.

Comment: @DarylGill thanks i have find error in my query

Comment: I wish to know who upvoting this kind of questions

Comment: @user2368299 What was  the error?

Comment: @DarylGill services.short_name = '{$service}' AND terminals.short_name = '{$terminal}' instead of  services.short_name = '{$service}' AND terminals.`name` = '{$terminal}'

Comment: **Don't quote/backtick your table & column names.**  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Answer (score 1):

Although "What I do incorrect" is an offtopic question for this site, the answer is:

Speaking of getting number of rows, you are doing everything correct.
The only cause for your troubles is some data/code inconsistency which you have to solve yourself.

Speaking of using prepared statements, you are using them wrong, adding variables directly into query while you ought to represent them with placeholders and bind later.